# Shortcut to launch Microsoft Whiteboard

Tags: windows, microsoft, run-dialog, whiteboard

When I right-click on Microsoft's whiteboard it is not displaying the option to open the file location.

I thought of using this technique to find the path of Microsoft's whiteboard and add that path to the system environment variable and launch the whiteboard through the run-dialog box.

Why it's not displaying the option to open file location when I click on Microsoft's whiteboard?

[image]

How do I launch Microsoft Whiteboard using the run command box?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a browser shortcut to https://whiteboard.office.com/

Whiteboard doesn't have "a file location" like a saved Word document. You just open the app and have all your whiteboards on the dashboard page.

The Whiteboard start menu shortcut is just an Edge shortcut, with a URL appended

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge_proxy.exe"  --profile-directory=Default --app-id=moohhcbepkadbkinknbfmbhdjdangdmh --app-url=https://whiteboard.office.com/ --app-launch-source=4`

Comment: Why it does have an open file location? There must be an executable file, isn't it?

Comment: The Open context menu is to open the application. Where are you seeing Open File as an option?

Comment: No spikey_richie when I added this in the run-dialog box it didn't work.

Comment: Your `--app-id=` might be different to mine.